# Dependency Resolution Issue Upon Installation of Plugins in Grails

Tags: maven, grails, dependencies, grails-plugin

So I am having a bit of issue with some of the Plugins I have installed in my Grails-app.  It looks like even once a plugin is installed I cannot import the package containing it into one of my classes without getting a "Cannot resolve symbol X" error. This is not the case for all plugins, only for some.

If I **do not** try import a package from certain Plugins I can compile and run my application without issue.  I am really at a loss here regarding why this is happening.

As a sanity check...

For a given Plugin I add any mavenRepo dependency OR runtime/build/compile insert into my BuildConfig.groovy, then install the Plugin inside my project with the **grails install-plugin X** command.  I then build the application.

Part of my buildconfig file is below.  ANY HELP or INSIGHT would be appreciated.

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"

    mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external"
    //excel import plugin
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases/"
    mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/"
    //joda time
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases/"
    mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/"
    mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/snapshots/"
    //execel export plugin
    mavenRepo("http://maven.touk.pl/nexus/content/repositories/releases")

}
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
     runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
}

plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.0"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    //runtime (":excel-export:0.1.4")
    runtime ":database-migration:1.1"

    compile ':cache:1.0.0'
    compile ":searchable:0.6.4"
    compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
    compile ":excel-import:1.0.0"
    compile ":excel-export:0.1.4"
    compile ":joda-time:1.4"


}
```

}

Comment: The more I look at this issue the more I think it is isolated to the excel import and excel export plugins.  Perhaps I am simply not implementing as intended.  I may just build what I need by importing the apache poi and constructing from the ground up.

Comment: It was the plugin causing issues.  Still not quite sure why, but I am bit new to managing Grails dependencies.